# ReactJS/Typescript: Cannot access string array passed as prop with numbered index

Tags: arrays, reactjs, typescript, react-props, react-functional-component

I'm relatively new to Typescript and am already in love, but I'm facing a weird problem right now:

I create a string array in the parent component, pass it down to a child component as prop and try to access the array with a numbered index from there.

This is the compile error i get:

> TypeScript error in /home/simon/development/portfolio/src/components/Projects/ImageSlider/ImageSlider.tsx(27,23):
> Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type '0' can't be used to index type 'PropsWithChildren'.
> Property '0' does not exist on type 'PropsWithChildren'.  TS7053

**ImageSlider.tsx (child)**

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import styles from "./ImageSlider.module.scss";
import { motion } from "framer-motion";
import Modal from "react-modal";

interface ImageSliderProps {
    images: string[];
}

const ImageSlider: React.FC<ImageSliderProps> = (images) => {
 
    const [index, setIndex] = useState<number>(0);

    const slideRight = () => { };
    const slideLeft = () => { };

    return (
        <div className={styles.slider_wrapper}>
            <button></button>
            <img src={images[0]} alt="" />
            <button></button>
        </div>
    );
};

export default ImageSlider;
```

**Parent Component:**

```
...

  let sliderImages: string[] = [
    "../../assets/Dotrice/dotrice-background.png",
    "../../assets/Dotrice/dotrice1.png",
    "../../assets/Dotrice/dotrice2.png",
    "../../assets/Dotrice/dotrice3.png",
    "../../assets/Dotrice/dotrice4.png",
  ];

return (
    <ImageSlider images={sliderImages} />
);

...
```

Do i have to explicitly set the type of the array index somewhere?

Thanks, have a great day and stay safe out there :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`images` is a field inside `props` object. You can either use destructuring:

```
const ImageSlider: React.FC<ImageSliderProps> = ({ images }) => {
```

or refer to the `props` firstly:

```
const ImageSlider: React.FC<ImageSliderProps> = (props) => {

<img src={props.images[0]} alt="" />
```